# In c++ how can I make class to recognize structures without including the header?

Tags: c++

Hello 
I have class AA.h and inside I have defined structure:

```
#include "BB.h"

Struct  foo{

};

Class AA 
{
…
void funa()
{
    BB bb;
    foo f;
    bb.func(f);
}
….
};
```

My question is do I have to include the AA.h also in the BB.h file so it will recognize   the foo struct or there is something else I can do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simplest is to create a header for your struct then include it in both your AA and BB.

```
#ifndef __FOO__H__
#define __FOO__H__
struct foo {

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `foo` in `BB.h`. But you can not include `AA.h` in `BB.h` as it will introduce a cyclic dependency and the compilation will fail. The simplest way to solve this is to provide the implementation of `A::funa` in a separate source file (normally with `.cpp` extension). You just need to *declare* `funa();` in the header file without any implementation. If you do this, then there is no need to include `BB.h` in `AA.h` (You need to include `BB.h` in `AA.cpp`) thus avoiding the cyclic dependency.